# How to bring the value of the last day of the previous week with DAX

Tags: dax

I have a simple table showing balance of each day of the week, I'd like to create a calculated measure to show balance change week on week. For this I have created a measure to show current day balance
Today's Balance = CALCULATE(SUM('Date Table'[Closing Balance]), FILTER('Date Table','Date Table'[Date] = TODAY())) which brings the correct result back of 198
but I'm struggling to create the measure to bring the value of the last day in previous week (192). I have created columns showing week number and week day, but unable to put it all together in the logical way.

[image]

I have tried various calculations with Calculate(SUM) and Filter combinations and Calculated(SELECTEDVALUE and FILTER), but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you share the table of the balance ?

Comment: Hi Amira, the table image is attached in the original post. I think I have figured the DAX formula myself:                                                 
Previous Week Balance = 
VAR EndOfLastWeek = TODAY() - WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)
REturn
CALCULATE(SUM('Date Table'[Closing Balance]),
FILTER(ALL('Date Table'), 'Date Table'[Date] = EndOfLastWeek))